# Extract key and value of array 2 where value array 1 = key array2

Tags: php, arrays

i didn't find a predefined php function to achieve it, there isn't one ?
I have 2 array :

array1 =

```
Array
(
    [0] => n
    [1] => m
    [2] => l
)
```

array2 =

```
Array
(
    [j] => 2
    [k] => 2
    [l] => 3758096384
    [m] => 3
)
```

Result expected : array3 =

```
Array 
(
        [l] => 3758096384
        [m] => 3
)
```

thanks for help,
Jess

Comment: what did you tried for this?

Comment: some "if in array" but i admit to be out here...i don't find anything acceptable..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect_key()`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect_key):

```
$array1 = array
(
    0 => 'n',
    1 => 'm',
    2 => 'l'
);

$array2 = array
(
    'j' => 2,
    'k' => 2,
    'l' => 3758096384,
    'm' => 3
);

$result = array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($array1));
```

Answer (score 3):

[`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) returns an array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments.

```
$a = array('n','m','l');
$b = array('j' => 2, 'k' => 2, 'l' => 3758096384, 'm' => 3);
$c = array_intersect_key($b, array_flip($a));
print_r($c); // Array ( [l] => 3758096384 [m] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $array3 = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $item){
     if (isset($array2[$item])){
        $array3[$item] = $array2[$item]
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is not ideal as `$item` may not be set for `$array2`

Comment: Now missing the if conditional. ;)

Comment: Still missing the `if` -- see donald's post.

Comment: code corrected, sorry but I didnt noticed that  `$array2[$item]` can be not set at first

Answer (score 0):

This should be work

```
 <?php
   // ... your array1 and array2 setup here

   $array3=array();
   foreach($array1 as $key) {
    if(isset($array2[$key])) $array3[$key] = $array2[$key];
   }
   var_dump($array3);
 ?>
```